# Display Product price without discount in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I apply Quantity based discount rule in woocommerce product. my product single pcs price is $ 12. if you purchase more than 12 products we apply flat $ 2 discount. 
[image]

before add 12 products in cart its display price correctly. after added cart. its display discounted price. i need to display before discount price in product page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`$product->get_regular_price();`